# Recommended browser for jasperreport server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

We're getting a lot of quirky behavior with JasperReports Server. Anyone know what the preferred browser is for it?  Their FAQ does not specify.

I've run into a lot of issues with IE 8. (problem seems to go away with 9.0)
Also with Chrome. "Tree failed to load" error.

However, firefox seems to be the most reliable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JasperReports-Server-CP-Install-Guide.pdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperserver/files/JasperServer/JasperServer%204.5.0/) it should support Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome and Safari. See section `3.4 Logging into JasperReports Server`:

> `2. Open a supported browser: Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Safari.`

Since that is the Community Project version I would assume it is the same for the paid version also. Also worth noting it did not seem to have and minimum version listed in there either.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a very ... i mean very ... loose "support"... we've run into several issues with IE8 and Chrome.  Firefox has been the only problem free so far. Terrible. Thank you for your help in locating this.

Comment: I agree completely and expect them to list a minimum version at least. And in the absence of such that it supports the latest versions of those browsers, which it obviously does not.

Answer (score 1):

See the following Platform Support Datasheet:  http://www.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/Jaspersoft%20Platform%20Support%20V4.7.pdf

Page 2 will give you the supported browsers for both the commercial and community editions.  If you run into issues using a supported browser, I recommend logging it on jasperforge.org.

For v4.7 the following is the list:

- Mozilla Firefox 3.5, 3.6, 4.0
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9.0
- Apple Safari 4.0, 5.0
- Google Chrome 6.0 or higher
- Adobe Acrobat 7 or higher
- Adobe Flash 8 or higher
- Apple iPad iOS Safari 4.x or higher

Comment: This list is an obvious lie. Talk about over-promising... Jasper tend to do that quite regularly.  Thank you for the info!